# UITableView UI Will Not Refresh to Data from New NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `UITableView` which is being filled from Core Data by a `NSFetchedResultsController`. Everything works great. However, I have just implemented a `UISegmentedControl` at the top of the `UITableView`, which I would like to sort the results. There are three segments: `@"All", @"Boys", @"Girls"`. In `viewDidLoad`, I instantiate a `NSDictionary` with three `NSFetchedResultsController`. Each has the exact same fetch request with a different predicate.

```
        allFetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"school.schoolID == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:[_schoolID intValue]]];
        boysFetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"school.schoolID == %@ AND gender == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:[_schoolID intValue]], @"M"];
        girlsFetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"school.schoolID == %@ AND gender == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:[_schoolID intValue]], @"F"];
```

When the `UISegmentControl` value is changed, I call a method which changes the view controller's "currentFetchedResultsController" instance variable to the corresponding `NSFetchedResultsController` for that segment, calls perform fetch, then calls `reloadData` on the tableView in the main thread.

```
- (void)showBoys
{
    self.currentFetchedResultsController = self.fetchResultsControllerDictionary[@"boys"];
    [self.currentFetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
    [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

It all seems to work great, except that the `UITableView` never seems to update its UI. It seems to show the correct number of sections for all, boys, and girls, but the object at each index doesn't change. For example, let's say we have 11 people in Core Data. Five guys, six girls. The view loads with the "All" segment pre-selected, so all 11 people load into the UITableView. However, when I switch the segment to "Boys", the number of rows will drop to five, but the objects in those rows never change. The `UITableView` will continue to show the first five objects that were already in the table, even if some are girls **(gender == "F"** in `Core Data`).

I know that the fetch is working properly because I have set up a small test:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    User *user = [self.currentFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"Username = %@ & Gender = %@", user.username, user.gender);
}
```

Now, when I select a row, it logs the correct username and gender that SHOULD be at that `indexPath`. However, the logged username is different than the one that appears in the `UITableView` at that row.

Table View Data Source Methods:

```
- (UserTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Home Ranked Cell";

    UserTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    User *user = [self.currentFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *name = user.name;
    if(!name || [name isEqualToString:@""])
        name = user.username;

    cell.name.text = name;

    UserTableViewCell *previousCell = nil;

    if(indexPath.row != 0)
        previousCell = (UserTableViewCell *)[self tableView:tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row - 1 inSection:indexPath.section]];

    NSInteger previousVotes = 0;

    if(previousCell)
        previousVotes = [previousCell.votes.text integerValue];

    if(!previousCell) {
        cell.rank.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", 1];
    } else if(previousVotes == [user.votes integerValue]) {
        cell.rank.text = previousCell.rank.text;
    } else {
        cell.rank.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [previousCell.rank.text integerValue] + 1];
    }

    if(user.profilePicture && user.profilePicture.thumbnailData && ![user.profilePicture.thumbnailData isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:user.profilePicture.thumbnailData options:0];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    }

    if(!cell.imageView.image)
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"xIcon.png"];

    cell.votes.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [user.votes integerValue]];
    cell.upButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.downButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    User *user = [self.currentFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"Username = %@ & Gender = %@", user.username, user.gender);
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView  
{
    return [self.currentFetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [self.currentFetchedResultsController sectionForSectionIndexTitle:title atIndex:index];
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.segmentControl;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.currentFetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id sectionInfo = [[self.currentFetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

I have tried nearly everything. I have gone through every related thread and nothing has worked. What am I doing wrong?

** Newest Findings:
When a cell is selected, the cell does not become highlighted (or show any UI change for that matter), unless it is the correct cell for that specific index path. For example, let's  say Sally is in row 0 for all Users, and Tom is in row 1. If I switch the UISegmentedControl to "Male" and tap the first cell (row 0, which currently shows Sally), there is absolutely no UI indication that the cell has been tapped, although     tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath still gets called, logging the cell information that belongs there (Tom's User info, since he belongs in row 0 of the "Male" Users).

Comment: Would you post the code from your UITableViewDataSource methods?

Comment: I have posted them now. I realize that the way I am handling this may be inefficient (switching between three separate NSFetchedResultsControllers), so I am very open to alternative solutions.

Comment: Have you implemented all the necessary delegate methods for `-[NSFetchResultsController delegate]`? http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller

Comment: @MikeD Yes I have implemented all the delegate methods mentioned in that tutorial. However, they don't seem to get called when I switch the segment, even though the fetch is being called successfully.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that it would be easier to put the segmentation logic into the fetched results controller method. When switching the segmented control, just set your FRC to `nil` and account for the proper filter in the FRC creation code. You do not need 3 FRCs. Thus:

```
-(void)segmentedControlDidChange:(UISegmentedControl*)control {
   self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

and when creating the FRC:

```
NSPredicate *basePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
       @"school.schoolID = %@", _schoolID];
NSPredicate *secondPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES];
NSInteger i = self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
if (i > 0) {
   secondPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
     @"gender = %@", i == 1 ? @"M" : @"F"];
}
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate 
   andPredicateWithSubPredicates:@[basePredicate, secondPredicate]];
```

Comment: While this does help to clean things up a bit, **it did not fix my problem.** Further testing has allowed me to find a new interesting aspect of the problem, which I will add to my original post.

Comment: While this did not solve your problem, it is still worth an up-vote ;-).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I made a silly mistake when initializing my UITableViewCell. Instead of calling

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

I was calling

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier **forIndexPath:indexPath**];
```

The latter returns the current UITableViewCell dequeued from the indexPath mentioned. For some reason, if the cell is dequeued from an existing cell, the properties on the cell are readonly, causing all of my changes to be simply ignored. I hope this helps someone in the future, as I did not see anything about this on Stack Overflow, I just happened to stumble upon my mistake after hours of analyzing each line of code.